# Reading values from Kafka Streams and check for errors

Tags: apache-kafka, quarkus, apache-kafka-streams

I'm totally new at kafka streams and I'm trying to use it in a quarkus application.
I'm trying to use it a bit like a db table.

I'm wondering if this is the correct approach and also if is there a way to check if kafka stream is down or if is in some sort of error state.

What is confusing me is that I've tried to to shut down my istance of kafka, but I didn't notice any kind of errors while trying to read the values.

In my case, I'm initializing the streams in this way:

```
public void start() {
   Properties properties = new Properties();
   properties.put(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG,   configurationProperties.kafkaStream().applicationId());
   properties.put(StreamsConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapServer);
   properties.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_KEY_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass());
   properties.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_VALUE_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass());

   kTable = builder.table(topic, Materialized.as(configurationProperties.kafkaStream().storeName()));

   streams = new KafkaStreams(builder.build(), properties);
   streams.start();

   keyValueStore = streams.store(StoreQueryParameters.fromNameAndType(configurationProperties.kafkaStream().storeName(), QueryableStoreTypes.keyValueStore()));
}
```

Next, I have some methods to retrieve the values by key like this:

```
  private String getValue(String key) {
    try {
      return keyValueStore.get(key);
    } catch (InvalidStateStoreException e) {
      throw new StatusServiceException(e);
    }
  }

  public int getNumber() {
    final String number = getValue("number");
    number = number != null && !number.isEmpty() ? Integer.parseInt(number) : 0;

    emitter.send(Record.of("number", String.valueOf(number++)));
    return number;
  }
```

To send to kafka I'm using an emitter:

```
  @Inject
  @Channel("status")
  private Emitter<Record<String, String>> emitter;
```

Are there some examples or documentation about something similar to this?
(For now I've tried to follow the tutorial available on confluent)

Thanks a lot in advance for your help.

Comment: go to https://quarkus.io/guides/ and type "kafka" in the search field. You will get all available documentation regarding kafka.

Answer (score 0):

Ktable and state store are in memory storage/caching provided by Kafka stream API. You read records from those in memory storage until records are available there and your own service is up and running.  If you shutdown Kafka srvers, you can't read from Kafka, but can continuously read from your service in memory storage.

Kafka is a log system, not exactly match with DB table. For example if you INSERT a record in a DB table and UPDATE it later, there will be only one  record in a DB. But Kafka keeps both that events(INSERT, UPDATE) as two different records in order.